# Android LiveData event sequence guarantees?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have the following code in my Fragment, subscribing to my ViewModel's LiveData events.

```
    viewModel.successfullyAddedEvent.observeEvent(this){
        // do result handling by shared view model to the calling fragment
        result.successfullyAddedEvent.postValue(Event(it))
        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }

    viewModel.successfullyEditedEvent.observeEvent(this){
        // do result handling by shared view model to the calling fragment
        result.successfullyEditedEvent.postValue(Event(it))
        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }

    viewModel.exitRequestedEvent.observeEvent(this){
        when(it){
            ExitReason.GetDetailsFailed -> {
                Toast.makeText(context, R.string.details_load_error, LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            ExitReason.UserCanceled -> { /* happy path */ }
        }

        findNavController().navigateUp()
    }
```

I have three places in this code where I'm calling `navigateUp` and I'd like to unify the navigation a bit.

It seems like it would be a code improvement to emit an `ExitRequestedEvent` from each case (successful add, successful edit, error case, user cancellation) and remove calls to `navigateUp` from those events, but I'm not sure about guarantees on receipt order.  That is, if I was to post values for a `successfullyAddedEvent` and then an `exitRequestedEvent` in my viewmodel like so:

```
// yay my thing happened successfully, emit events
successfullyAddedEvent.postValue(Event(contentAdded))
exitRequestedEvent.postValue(Event(ExitReason.AddSuccessful))
```

can I be guaranteed that I'll handle the add event (which sets the result on the shared result ViewModel) before I exit this fragment, so that the calling fragment always has a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData#postvalue), `postValue` just means posting the task to main thread if you are not on it, so unless you have `setValue` somewhere in your code as well, the order should be guaranteed.

If you want to absolutely guarantee the order (even though not necessary), you can use `setValue()` for that, but you have to make sure it happens on the main thread.